# Как оптимизировать код для карточки товара?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужна помощь в 2 вопросах.
Для понимания даю ссылку на пример:http://takercorporation.com/

1) При наведении на карточку товара появляется блок с выбором изображений.
Как это сделать для одной карты я знаю, но проблема в том, что таких карточек будет много.
Как можно оптимизировать код, чтобы не было повторов?
Код JavaScript (jQuery):

```
var itemCatalog_1 = $('.products__item_1 .slider_mini_item'),
    itemCatalog_2 = $('.products__item_2 .slider_mini_item'),
    imageCatalog_1 = $('.products__item_1 .products__item_slider img'),
    imageCatalog_2 = $('.products__item_2 .products__item_slider img');

itemCatalog_1.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemCatalogThis = $(this).attr('href');
    itemCatalog_1.removeClass('slider_mini_item_active');
    $(this).toggleClass('slider_mini_item_active');
    imageCatalog_1.removeClass('products__item_slider_active');
    $(itemCatalogThis).addClass('products__item_slider_active');
});
itemCatalog_2.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemCatalogThis = $(this).attr('href');
    itemCatalog_2.removeClass('slider_mini_item_active');
    $(this).toggleClass('slider_mini_item_active');
    imageCatalog_2.removeClass('products__item_slider_active');
    $(itemCatalogThis).addClass('products__item_slider_active');
```

2) При клике на категорию (в примере по ссылке от "Одежда" до "Распродажа") появляется каталог, как его закрыть при повторном нажатии на категорию?
Код JavaScript (jQuery):

```
var tabsHeaderLinks = $('.header__level-3_link a'),
    tabsHeader = $('.header__level-3_link'),
    tabsHeaderContent = $('.header__level-4_grid');

tabsHeaderLinks.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tabsLink = $(this).attr('href');
    tabsHeaderLinks.removeClass('header__level-3_link-active');
    $(this).toggleClass('header__level-3_link-active');
    tabsHeaderContent.removeClass('header__level-4_grid-active');
    $(tabsLink).toggleClass('header__level-4_grid-active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы же уже знаете про `this`:

```
$(".slider_mini_item").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemCatalogThis = $(this).attr('href');
    $(".slider_mini_item_active").not(this).removeClass('slider_mini_item_active');
    $(this).toggleClass('slider_mini_item_active');
    $(this).removeClass('products__item_slider_active'); // вот здесь не понял
    $(itemCatalogThis).addClass('products__item_slider_active');
});
```

Comment: При повторном нажатии на малую картинку выше выбранной изменение не происходит

Comment: @MarianVytak создайте, пожалуйста, действующий пример в вопросе

Comment: Пример по ссылке обновлен.
Возможно нужно обновить страницу через shift+f5